# parsing xml data from google maps api

Tags: php, xml, google-maps-api-3

I must get the directional information only from the xml data with my specified coordinates. here is my code

```
    <?php 
$string= simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=37.036543,35.288086&destination=36.997415,35.288067&sensor=false");
    print_r ($string);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

    $result = $xml->xpath('/WebServiceRequest/result[2]/message/text()');

    while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
        echo 'b/c: ',$node,"\n";
    }
    ?>
```

but I get the following error:
 Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

and of course there is rest of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do below implementation. The xpath you had written I not found anything like that in your response XML from Google. So I given hint based on what I receive response from Google. I assumed that you require `<step>` element and its children to implement/resolve your requirement. In the below you can do your necessary changes based on your further requirement and below is ready to run.

I have also put `print_r($item)` for your debug purpose. So have a look on it also.

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=37.036543,35.288086&destination=36.997415,35.288067&sensor=false");
$result = $xml->xpath('//step');

foreach($result as $item){
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($item);
    echo "travel_mode::".$item->travel_mode;
    echo "<br/>start_location::";
        //child elements of start_location element
        foreach($item->start_location as $child)
        {
            echo "<br/>lat::".$child->lat;
            echo "<br/>lng::".$child->lng;
        }
        //like above you can get other elements as well their child elements too.
    echo "<hr/>";
}
?>
```